# Integer and not DECIMAL

Tags: sql, teradata

Why I am getting Integer in this output (I am expecting DECIMAL)
Database flavor is Teradata
What am I doing wrong?

```
CASE WHEN sub_e.LSD IS NOT NULL  THEN CAST(baba.amt AS DECIMAL(10,2))  
ELSE 0
END
-
(
SUM(
     CASE 

        WHEN sub_e.LSD IS NOT NULL          
        THEN ch.actv_amt  * (1 + ch.tax_percent_rate/100) 

     ELSE 0

     END
    )
)
 +
 CASE WHEN  
                sub_e.LSD IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(sub_e.PWC, 0)
 ELSE 0
 END                

  AS ODTS,
```

Comment: Are you shure it's an INT?
Did you check it by adding a column TYPE(ODTS)?

Based on the "CAST baba-mnt AS DECIMAL(10,2)" the resulting datatype should be DECIMAL.
Can you show the datatypes of all those columns?

Comment: thanks for the answer - the problem was in the definition of a solumn inside the table where the result of the query above is doing INSERT

Answer (score 1):

If `TAX_RATE_PERCENT` is not defined as a `DECIMAL` of ***sufficient precision*** then your calculation of `(1 + TAX_RATE_PERCENT/100)` will be incorrect.

`SELECT 6/100; -- 0 (zero - Integer division)`

`SELECT 6.0/100; -- 0.1 (rounding rules based on precision of numerator)`

`SELECT 6.00/100; -- 0.06 (expected answer)`

`SELECT CAST(6 AS DECIMAL(2,1))/100; -- 0.1 (rounding rules based on precision of numerator)`

`SELECT CAST(6 AS DECIMAL(3,2))/100; -- 0.06 (expected answer)`

For more details on DECIMAL data type behavior in Teradata see Dnoeth's explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574015/decimal-types-in-teradata).

Comment: this is exactly the answer that gives the best solution to my problem. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: Added link to your other question with Dnoeth's more precise answer on the resulting precision for decimal operations in Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the definition of a solumn inside the table where the result of the query above is doing INSERT