# DECIMAL Types in Teradata

Tags: sql, type-conversion, teradata

Can somebody please explain the following result I get in Teradata:

```
SELECT TYPE(CAST (2.3 AS DECIMAL(18,4)) * CAST (2.3 AS DECIMAL(18,4))  )
```

The result is:

```
DECIMAL(18,8)
```

I was expecting DECIMAL(18,4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every DBMS has it's own rules regarding calculations involving Decimals.

Teradata's basic rules are:
When you add/substract/divide DECIMALs the resulting fractional precision is the greater of both operands, e.g. dec(10,2) + dec(10,4) = dec(xx,4)

But when you multiply the fractional digits are added, e.g.dec(10,2) * dec(10,4) = dec(xx,6)

The overall precision has some more rules (some depending on the dbscontrol MAxDecimal setting).

And then there's the most important rule, people tend to forget:
After each calculation the result is rounded to this precision.

```
sel 2.0/3.00 * 100, 100*2.0/3.00;

    *** Query completed. One row found. 2 columns returned.
    *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

 ((2.0/3.00)*100)   ((100*2.0)/3.00)
-----------------  -----------------
            67.00              66.67
```

Dieter

Comment: Thanks for your reply. according to what you wrote (and I testet it in Assistant) the rounding rules are based on precision of a denominator. Example: SEL 2.0/3.00 results in 0.67 Can you please confirm this?
Answer from Rob in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404617/integer-and-not-decimal/17430737?noredirect=1#17430737 was that the rounding rules based on precision of NUMERATOR. Please send me a feedback. Thx

Comment: Dnoeth's answer is more accurate than what I gave in my explanation.

Comment: As i wrote it's based on both operands, SEL 2.00/3.0 also results in 0.67

Comment: Thanks guys for great and precise feedback!